# how can i set the quantity of a product in my localstorage in javascript

Tags: javascript

I've been trying to build an ecommerce website for a project in javascript (I'm a student) and I'm having trouble to set the quantity of a product into my localStorage. There's a text field where you can set a quantity for the product (1 to 100) but no matter what value I put into it it adds +1. Every other functions work though. Here's what I tried :

```
addToCart.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
let cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart')) || []
let chosenColor = colors.options[colors.selectedIndex].text
let chosenQuantity = quantity.value[quantity.selectedIndex]
let newItem = {
image: data[i].imageUrl,
name: data[i].name,
price: data[i].price,
color: chosenColor,
quantity: quantity,
}
cart.push(newItem)
localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(cart))
console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart')))
```

I'm very new to javascript and stackoverflow so sorry if you have troubles to understand the code or the question, I'll obviously be available to answer any question. Thank you very much!

Here's the HTML tag i fetched :

```
<input type="number" name="itemQuantity" min="1" max="100" value="0" id="quantity">
```

in JS :

```
const quantity = document.getElementById('quantity')
```

My variable chosenQuantity might be wrongly written, I'm not sure about it

EDIT: I tried to get the value set in the input but I don't feel like the value is related to how many items I put into my LS. Here is my new code :

```
addToCart.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
let cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart')) || []
let chosenColor = colors.options[colors.selectedIndex].text
let chosenQuantity = parseInt(document.getElementById('quantity').value)
let newItem = {
image: data[i].imageUrl,
name: data[i].name,
price: data[i].price,
color: chosenColor,
quantity: chosenQuantity,
}
cart.push(newItem)
localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(cart))
console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart')))
})
```

Comment: What is working, what isn't ? It seems fine for me but you maybe need something specific

Comment: there's a text field where you can set a quantity for the product (1 to 100) but no matter what value I put into it it adds +1. Every other function works though

Comment: Didn't you want to set `quantity: chosenQuantity` instead of `quantity: quantity` ? :)

Comment: I created a const to get the element, that's what I was referring to!

const quantity = document.getElementById('quantity')

EDIT: I see what you mean, my bad. I just tried to change it to chosenQuantity but it didn't work :/

Comment: Does my edited answer respond your question ? (use `let chosenQuantity = parseInt(quantity.value)` to init the `chosenQuantity` var)

Answer (score 0):

you use `quantity` instead of `chosenQuantity`, is that the problem ?

```
let newItem = {
image: data[i].imageUrl,
name: data[i].name,
price: data[i].price,
color: chosenColor,
quantity: chosenQuantity,
}
```

EDIT: after post edit

If it's a text field (`<input type="number" />`) you can take the value with only `parseInt(quantity.value)` that's not an array:

```
let chosenQuantity = parseInt(quantity.value)
```

If it doesn't answer your question, we need more info about the code (quantity/data init etc.)

Comment: It doesn't work either, it adds only 1 product to my LS, I tried it also with the code Mykola MASTEMA suggested me but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

If i got the point, you should search the item by name in the cart. If not, you add it to cart. If found - you get the itom info in localStorage, increate quantity and write new dat to LS. Like this:

```js
let cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart')) || [];

const chosenItem = cart.find(item => item.name === data[i].name);

if (!chosenItem) {
    let chosenColor = colors.options[colors.selectedIndex].text
    let chosenQuantity = quantity.value[quantity.selectedIndex]
    let newItem = {
        image: data[i].imageUrl,
        name: data[i].name,
        price: data[i].price,
        color: chosenColor,
        quantity: chosenQuantity,
    }

    cart.push(newItem)
} else {
    chosenItem.quantity += chosenQuantity;
    cart.splice(cart.indexOf(chosenItem), 1, chosenItem); 
}

localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(cart))
```

Comment: It returns that chosenQuantity is not defined, I also tried to put chosenQuantity outside the condition but it adds nothing to the LS. I might have written the variable wrong but I don't know how I could do it